# how can I add an error_response when identityserver sends unauthorized 401 message

Tags: identityserver4

I am using identityserver4 to secure my apis.

When the token expires, in addition to sending error message 401, how can I send a json object in the body with the error description? I am using .net core.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a spec for how to do this:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3

You can provide additional info in the `WWW-Authenticate` response header.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example",error="invalid_token",error_description="The access token expired"
```

It should be possible to replace this header if token validation fails via the middleware JwtBearerEvents object.

Answer (score 0):

As other response mentioned this is possible by setting WWW-Authenticate header in Unauthorized response. Here is code on API's `startup.cs` to make this happen:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
                options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.Audience = "api1";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    };                    
                });
}

private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is SecurityTokenExpiredException expiredException)
            {
                context.Response.Headers.TryAdd(HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate,
                    new StringValues(new[] {
                        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        "error=\"invalid_token\"",
                        "error_description=\"The access token expired\""
                    }));
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

The JWT handler is from Microsoft and IdentityServer using it internally.

Comment: thanks for answering. What I really need is when error 401 is displayed in addition to sending the error_response in the header this information is also sent in the response body. I share the code of my startup

Comment: did you try to manipulate the response? as much as I know this is where you can change and you cant add data magically just by setting a property or sth like this.

Comment: Sure I tried but without success, I can not solve it. Do you have an example of this type to implement it?